# String-1 > startWord

Tags: java

I was going through practice questions on CodingBat and I came across this one. It said:

> "Given a string and a second "word" string, we'll say that the word matches the string if it appears at the front of the string, except its first char does not need to match exactly. On a match, return the front of the string, or otherwise return the empty string. So, so with the string "hippo" the word "hi" returns "hi" and "xip" returns "hip". The word will be at least length 1. "

So far this is the solution I came up with. It works for the most part, however I get one error shown below:

> Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 (line number:3)

This occurs for the case -->> `startWord("", "i")`. How could this error be fixed?

```
public String startWord(String str, String word) {

    String first = str.substring(1, str.length());
    String second = word.substring(1, word.length());

    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    } 
    if (str.startsWith(word)) {
        return str.substring(0, word.length());
    } 
    else if (first.startsWith(second)) {
        return str.substring(0, word.length());
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: When `str` is `""`, what do you expect `str.substring(1, str.length())` will do?

Comment: The program will freak out because the index specified does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your

```
 if (str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
 }
```

as a first statement your function, so that the zero length string don't throw the exception.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about doing that when I got that error but I never tried it out to see if it would actually work. Thanks for the clarification. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, I finally decided to sign up since I use it so much for reference. People on here are so helpful :)